# Deleting an invalid inmemory layer from the Table of Contents

Tags: arcgis-desktop, c#, add-in

I am writing an ESRI addin (in c#) where in_memory layers are used. When the user opens the map document and activates the tool, the tool checks whether the in_memory layer is valid or not, and if it is not valid (has a red exclamation mark) it should delete the layer and recreate it for the current session.

I am using the following to delete the layer

```
mxDoc.FocusMap.DeleteLayer(dsAOI);
```

but once it deletes it i then get a message box saying:

> Object not set to an instance of an object

I have tried to disconnect the layer before I delete it using IDataLayer2.Disconnect

```
   IFeatureLayer toDelete = dsAOI as IFeatureLayer;
   IDataLayer2 dl2 = toDelete as IDataLayer2;
   dl2.Disconnect();
```

but that results in the error message:

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM
>   component

Has anyone got ideas on what I might be doing wrong, or a better way to get round this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have cracked it, after the delete statement I added `mxDoc.UpdateContents();` which seems to have worked,